# Django: list_filter and foreign key fields

Tags: django, list, filter, foreign-keys

Django doesn't support getting foreign key values from list_display or list_filter (e.g foo__bar). I know you can create a module method as a workaround for list_display, but how would I go about to do the same for list_filter? Thanks.

Comment: seems that django used to support this feature before version 1.2.4. I don't know why they disabled it now.

Answer (score 40):

Django supports list_filter with foreign key fields

```
# models.py:
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

# admin.py:
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('foo__name')
```

From documentation: Field names in list_filter can also span relations using the __ lookup

Answer (score 16):

Well, the docs say that you can may use `ForeignKey` field types in `list_filter`:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

An example:

```
# models.py:
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

# admin.py:
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('foo')
```

If you want to filter by a field from the related model, there's a patch on the way to make this work (will probably be merged into 1.2 as it seems):

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3400

Comment: Thanks. Although I am looking for a workaround and not a patch. Sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: This feature no longer works.  Foreign key fields simply don't render on the sidebar -- it's as if you didn't specify them.

Comment: This is now working, but it needs to be a "list" even though it is a single item. for the above example, use `list_filter = ('foo',)`, per [official dev documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/filters/)

Comment: `list_filter = ('foo',)` doesn't work for me in Django 4.2, the filter doesn't appear.

Answer (score 4):

solution from this page worked for me http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/fixing-django-124s-suspiciousoperation-filtering/

define

```
class SmarterModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    valid_lookups = ()
    def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, *args, **kwargs):
        if lookup.startswith(self.valid_lookups):
            return True
         return super(SmarterModelAdmin, self).lookup_allowed(lookup, *args, **kwargs)
```

then allow the lookup for certain foreign key field

```
class PageAdmin(SmarterModelAdmin):
   valid_lookups = ('parent')
```

Comment: By "('parent')" do you mean "tuple('parent')". If not, then remove the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

If you construct the URL for the changelist manually then Django has no problems following relationships. For example:

```
/admin/contact/contact/?participant__event=8
```

or

```
/admin/contact/contact/?participant__event__name__icontains=er
```

Both work fine (although the latter doesn't add 'distinct()' so might have duplicates but that won't usually be an issue for filters)

So you just need to add something to the page that creates the correct links. You can do this either with by overriding the changelist template or by writing a custom filterspec. There are several examples I found by Googling - particularly on [Django Snippets](http://www.djangosnippets.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create custom filters since Django 1.4 by overriding `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter` class.

More information :

1. [Admin list_filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) ;
2. [Django-1.4 release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#list-filters-in-admin-interface).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and really needed a solution. I have a workaround that lets you create a filter on a FK related model property. You can even traverse more than one FK relationship. It creates a new FilterSpec subclass that subclasses the default RelatedFilterSpec used to give you a filter on a ForeignKey field.

See http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2260/

Answer (score 1):

The Haes answer works perfectly, but if the `__` looks up to another ForeignKey field, you end up with a blank result. You must place another `__` lookup, until it points to the real field.

In my case: `list_filter = ('place__condo__name', )`

my models.py:

```
class Condo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    ...

class Place(models.Model):
    condo = models.ForeignKey(Condo)
    ...

class Actions(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    ...
```