# Filter by a virtual name in the admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

**Django4.1**

```
class Exercise(NameMixin,
               UrlMixin,
               PriorityMixin,
               CommentMixin):
    unit = models.ForeignKey('vocabulary_units.Unit',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True, )



class Phrase(models.Model):

    exercise = models.ForeignKey('vocabulary_exercises.Exercise',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=False)

    @property
    def unit(self):
        result = self.exercise.unit
        return result
```

A phase belongs to an exercise, excercise belongs to a unit.

The problem is that in the admin site I'd like to organise for phrases a filter by unit.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: But how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '__' lookup method in the `list_filter` fields. Also you didn't post how the `Unit` model looks, this code will filter in IDs basically, you probably will want to use `exercise__unit__name` or similar:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class PhraseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['exercise__unit']
```

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065036/django-list-filter-and-foreign-key-fields/2065133#2065133)